# Audio clip getting stuck

Tags: java, javasound

I am seeing some strange behaviour with `Clip` instances in Java.

The purpose of the class I am working on is to keep count of the number of `Clip` instances containing the same sound sample (indexed by `URI`.)  When the application requests to play a clip and there are already three or more clips from the same source already playing, the following steps are performed:

- Sort the currently-playing clips by a weighted sum of `PAN` and `framePosition`.
- Select the clip with the highest value as the one to be stopped and re-started.
- Re-start the clip (the following method):

```
void restart(Clip clip, float gain, float pan) {
    clip.stop();
    clip.flush();
    pan = Math.max(-1f, Math.min(pan, 1f));
    ((FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN))
                        .setValue(gain);
    ((FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN))
                        .setValue(pan);
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();
}
```

Strange behaviour occurs if this method is called many times in quick succession (e.g. 20 times within 1ms):

- The clip plays
- The clip fires a `START` event to signal that it has started playing
- The clip never fires a `STOP` event.
- Subsequent calls to `stop` and `start` have no effect (but do not throw exceptions.)
- [getFramePosition](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#getFramePosition%28%29) always returns `0`, even when the clip is audible (for the last time.)

Any idea what could be causing this?

I don't think it's a threading issue (at least not in my code.)  Only one thread is calling the public methods of my class (and they are all `synchronized` anyway)

---

Might be related to [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6251460).

Comment: As a quick test you might try syncrhonizing on the clip instance for the entire of  the restart method to rule out any threading problems.

Comment: @mdma, I will try that but I would be surprised if it made a difference.  `restart` is called only from another `synchronized` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls to `DataLine.start` and `DataLine.stop` are **already synchronized** on the `DataLine`'s mixer inside [`AbstractDataLine`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/media/sound/AbstractDataLine.java.html).

I strongly suspect that somewehere down the call stack (below `implStart()`/`implStop()` of whatever `DataLine` incarnation you got, very likely inside the native `nStart`/`nstop`) **at least one asynchronous call is made**, thus resulting in the race condition you observe.

It would be impossible for you to work around this kind of problem using `synchronized` or any other Java construct without more intimate knowledge of the native implementation that is called.

A **viable, immediate workaround could be** to close the old clip and open a new instance instead of rewinding the old one.  Not optimal, but it may well do the trick pending a deeper investigation.

In order to be able to perform the aforementioned deeper investigation, one would have to know what platform you are on, as well as a confirmation of the actual (implementation) class names of your `Clip` and `Mixer` instances.

**UPDATE**

In parallel, please use introspection to set `com.sun.media.sound.Printer.trace = true` (or provide your own implementation of [`com.sun.media.sound.Printer`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/media/sound/Printer.java.html) in the `CLASSPATH`.)

Essentially [`DirectClip.open()` spawns](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/media/sound/DirectAudioDevice.java.html#1181) a [thread](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/media/sound/DirectAudioDevice.java.html#1391) which accesses several [volatile variables](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/media/sound/DirectAudioDevice.java.html#371) (of particular interest being `doIO`) in a non-threadsafe manner, which could potentially result in  the main playback loop hanging.

You can confirm (or infirm) this (in conjunction with the `Printer` traces) by forcing a [thread dump](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) at the time of the apparent hang, and inspecting the playback thread state/stack trace (or use a debugger.)

If `doIO` etc. access turns out *not* to be the problem then continuing to dig at the native implementations is still the thing to do; if `doIO` etc. access *does* turn out to be the problem then again, there is no easy fix (you can try to use introspection to grab `DirectClip.thread` and signal it periodically in case it stalls because of `doIO` -- again, to be confirmed.)

Comment: The mixer is a `com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice` and the clip is a `com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice.DirectClip`.

Comment: ...and the platform is...? :)

Comment: Romascanul, Originally on Windows XP.  Reproduced on Vista (but it happens less frequently on Vista than on XP.)  Failed to reproduce on Ubuntu, but that was running on a netbook with only one processor core (which may mask the problem if it is a threading issue in a library.)

Comment: OK, thx.  Try to do the stuff in the post *UPDATE*, and see what comes out of it -- with a bit of luck "that is it"...